# Linking tables using Scope_Identity on Insert...Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to insert values from excel to sql server. I have a table with an Identity(1,1) field and I want this to link to another table.

Example:

```
ID      Vegetables
1       Corn/Peas
2       Beans/Spinach
```

Want to link to a table that looks like:

```
ID      Vegetable
1       Corn
1       Peas
2       Beans
3       Spinach
```

I have a coded split string function that takes a string and delimiter and splits it, returning a table.

I want to use this on the insert statement and I have a variable

```
@scopeID = SCOPE_Identity()
```

I think I need to use cross apply but not sure because I am essentially adding to both tables.

I have something like:

```
Insert Into [VegetableTable](
[Vegetable])

Values(
@Vegetable --pulling from Excel VBA
)

Declare @scopeID Int
Set @scopeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

any help on writing the way to get table 2 would be really helpful.

Thanks

Edit:
I have a split string that returns something like:

```
ID           Vegetable             Want (ScopeID)
1            Corn                      1
2            Peas                      1
3            Broccoli                  1
1           Beans                      2
2          Spinach                     2
```

If I added broccoli to the first list. But I need to match these up so my scope identity pairs with the vegetable, in this case 2 separate strings.

Comment: Look up a standard split function (there are a ton of them available). Your delimited would be '/'. Here's a link with a bunch of them: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Please see edit. it may highlight where i need help better

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query if you have fixed number of delimiters.

```
;with cte as (
select *, substring(vegetables, 0,charindex('/', vegetables)) firsthalf, substring(vegetables, charindex('/', vegetables)+1, len(vegetables)) secondhalf from veg 
) select id, firsthalf from cte union all
select id,secondhalf from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then I would simply create an initial excel import table with a trigger defined on the table. The import table will generate your ID and the trigger on the import table can then transform the data into the format you want. Below an example of the table import table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VegetableTableExcel](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Vegetables] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_VegetableTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Next the result table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vegetables](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VegetableName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Finally, the trigger in the original import that transforms your source import from excel:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SplitVegetable ON VegetableTableExcel
AFTER INSERT
AS


    MERGE INTO Vegetables AS [Target]
    USING   (

                SELECT  [Source].ID
                        ,Vegetables.VegetableName
                FROM    inserted [Source]
                CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT  splitdata AS VegetableName
                                FROM    dbo.SplitString([Source].Vegetables, '/')
                            ) Vegetables        
            ) AS [Source]
    ON ([Target].[ID] = [Source].[ID])  AND ([Target].[VegetableName] = [Source].[VegetableName])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT  (
                 [ID]
                ,[VegetableName]
            ) VALUES 
            (
                [Source].[ID] 
                ,[Source].[VegetableName]
            ) ;
```

For completeness I have included the splitter function used to split the string containing the vegetable names below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```